# Can you use nth-child to select the last 3 items and choose odd or even?

Tags: css, css-selectors

**Scenario**

Say for example I have the following:

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9

<ul>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
    <li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li>
    <li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li>
</ul>
```

I have a default background for odd and even:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ff0000;
} 

li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #00ff00;
}
```

**Question**

But I want to apply a different background for the last 3 results, also depending upon whether they are even or odd:

```
li:nth-last-child(-n + 3)(even) {
    background: #0000ff;
}

li:nth-last-child(-n + 3)(odd) {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat the `:nth-child` portion as well:

```
li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(even) {
    background: #0000ff;
}

li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

Also, depending on how many elements you have, `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-last-child(odd)` (as well as their `even` counterparts) may select different elements.

Comment: Is it possible to select even and odd after an nth-child(or a child with specific class)?

Comment: @Venu Gopal: You can use the `~` combinator to select following siblings but it depends on what you mean by "even" and "odd". You may want to post a new question.

Comment: @boltclocks-a-unicorn See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564695/select-even-and-odd-childs-of-a-particular-class-after-a-specific-class-child)