# Select even and odd childs of a particular class after a specific class child

Tags: css, css-selectors

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="b">b7</div>
  <div class="b">b8</div>
  <div class="a">a1</div>
  <div class="b">b1</div>
  <div class="b">b2</div>
  <div class="b">b3</div>
  <div class="a">a2</div>
  <div class="a">a3</div>
  <div class="b">b4</div>
  <div class="b">b5</div>
  <div class="b">b6</div>
</div>
```

I want odd siblings of class b which comes after class 'a' i.e b1, b3, b4, b6 (should not b7)are to be selected.
is it possible using CSS?

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/VM3Xs/). But the selector length depends on number of `.b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/VM3Xs/)

```
.a+.b, .a+.b+.b+.b{
    background: red;
}
```

I'm using adjacent sibling character. But this solution may not be feasible when the the `.b` count is more.

Comment: Please post the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can (you do mean even tho, instead of odd, if you want to select b1, b3, b4 and b6):

```
.a ~ .b:nth-child(even) {
    color: red;
}
```

Also check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HEMC/)

Comment: The `.a ~` part of this selector is completely unnecessary. The even `.b` elements are even regardless of whatever elements come before them.

Comment: @James Donnelly: To be fair, the question did ask only for `.b` elements occurring after `.a`. While it's unnecessary for the markup given in the question, it's not completely unnecessary for any structure.